# How to check for overlaps and continue to count sum for the unaccounted elements moving forward (jagged array)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, overlap, jagged-arrays

For example I have this array in which later I would need to search through:

```
private static readonly decimal[] ArrayWithFiveElements = { 0.1m, 0.2m, 0.3m, 0.4m, 0.5m };
```

And then I have a arrays of ranges that defines which elements to search for:

```
            decimal[][] ranges =
            {
                new[] { 0.1m, 0.2m },
                new[] { 0.4m, 0.5m },
                new[] { decimal.Zero, decimal.One },
            };
```

Now what my code should do is return the number of occurences of the elements that match the range criteria. Now if I try to count these ranges without the last array i'll get 4: 0.1m, 0.2m, 0.4m and 0.5m, but if we try to count it with the last one (which overlaps the previuos two arrays) I will get the result 9: 0.1m, 0.2m, 0.4m, 0.5m, 0.1m, 0.2m, 0.3m 0.4m and 0.5m. What I want in my result is 5: 0.1m, 0.2m, 0.3m, 0.4m, 0.5m .

How can I count through the array and if the array overlaps with some of the elements in the previuos arrays it ignores them, and if there is a uncounted element it will add to the count instead of adding everything multiple times it overlaps.

This is my code so far:

```
        public static int GetDecimalsCount(decimal[] arrayToSearch, decimal[][] ranges)
        {
            if (arrayToSearch is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
            }
            else if (ranges is null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ranges));
            }
            else
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < ranges.Length; x++)
                {
                    if (ranges[x] is null)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ranges));
                    }
                    else if ((ranges[x].Length > 0 && ranges[x].Length < 2) || ranges[x].Length > 2)
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentException(null);
                    }
                }

                int sum = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayToSearch.Length; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < ranges.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (ranges[j].Length == 0)
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        else if (arrayToSearch[i] >= ranges[j][0] && arrayToSearch[i] <= ranges[j][1])
                        {
                            sum++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return sum;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There heaps of ways to do this, one is to use `Any`

```
public static int GetDecimalsCount(decimal[] arrayToSearch, decimal[][] ranges)
{
   if (arrayToSearch == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
   if (ranges == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ranges));
   if (ranges.Any(x =>x?.Length != 2)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ranges",nameof(ranges));

   return arrayToSearch.Sum(item =>
         ranges.Any(range =>
            item >= range[0] &&
            item <= range[1]) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rc7aOx)

You could also can save your self some hassle use a record for the range

**Given**

```
public record Range(decimal From, decimal To)
{
   public bool Check(decimal value) => value >= From && value <= To;
}
```

**Example**

```
public static int GetDecimalsCount(decimal[] arrayToSearch, Range[] ranges)
{
   if (arrayToSearch == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
   if (ranges == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ranges));

   return arrayToSearch.Sum(item => ranges.Any(range => range.Check(item)) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var ranges = new Range[]
{
   new( 0.1m, 0.2m ),
   new(0.4m, 0.5m),
   new(decimal.Zero, decimal.One)
};
```

If you needed to this in loops

```
public static int GetDecimalsCount(decimal[] arrayToSearch, decimal[][] ranges)
{
   if (arrayToSearch == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(arrayToSearch));
   if (ranges == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ranges));
   if (ranges.Any(x => x?.Length != 2)) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid ranges", nameof(ranges));

   var sum = 0;

   foreach (var item in arrayToSearch)
      foreach (var range in ranges)
         if (item >= range[0] && item <= range[1])
         {
            sum++;
            break;
         }

   return sum;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this, by using loops like my example above, without using Linq?